# C++ Dynamic, Array Based Integer Stack

Tags: c++, arrays

Im just starting to learn C++ programming and for exercise i found this task. I have to write a dynamic, array based integer stack. This is what i have got so far.

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;


class DynamicIntegerStack
{
private:
    int *bottom_;
    int *top_;
    int size_;
public:
    DynamicIntegerStack(int n = 20){
        bottom_ = new int[n];
        top_ = bottom_;
        size_ = n;
    }

    int getSize(){ return size_; }

    void push(int c){
        if (!full()){
            *top_ = c;
            top_++;
        }
        else{
            resize(size_ * 2);
            *top_ = c;
            top_++;
        }
    }

    void resize(int newSize){
        //Allocate new array and copy in data
        int *newArray = new int[newSize];
        memcpy(newArray, bottom_, size_);

        // Set the top to the new array
        top_ = newArray + (top_ - bottom_);

        // Delete old array
        delete[] bottom_;

        // Update pointers and size
        bottom_ = newArray;
        size_ = newSize;

        cout << "array has been resized" << endl;
    }

    int num_items() {
        return (top_ - bottom_);
    }
    char pop(){
        top_--;
        return *top_;
    }
    int full() {
        return (num_items() >= size_);
    }
    int empty() {
        return (num_items() <= 0);
    }
    void print(){
        cout << "Stack currently holds " << num_items() << " items: ";
        for (int *element = bottom_; element<top_; element++) {
            cout << " " << *element;
        }
        cout << "\n";
    }
    ~DynamicIntegerStack(){ // stacks when exiting functions
        delete[] bottom_;
    }
};
int main(){
    DynamicIntegerStack s(5);
    s.print(); cout << "\n";
    s.push(1); s.push(3); s.push(5); s.push(10); s.push(15);
    s.print(); cout << "\n";
    s.push(20);
    s.print(); cout << "\n";
    cout << "Popped value is: " << s.pop() << "\n";
    s.print(); cout << "\n";
    s.push(30);
    s.print(); cout << "\n";
    s.pop();
    s.pop();
    s.print(); cout << "\n";
    while (!s.empty()) s.pop();
    if (s.num_items() != 0) {
        cout << "Error: Stack is corrupt!\n";
    }
    s.print(); cout << "\n";
    // destructor for s automatically called
    system("pause"); // execute M$-DOS' pause command
    return 0;
}
```

It works fine untill the array is full and i resize it. After that instead of integers it starts printing this.
[image: DynamicIntegerStack]

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Does it throw a hint your direction if I tell you (a) `memcpy` uses a **byte** count for the size argument, and (b) `int` is *very* likely *larger* than a single byte on your platform ? Perhaps try `std::copy(bottom_, bottom_+size_, newArray);` during the resize and ditch the `memcpy`. [See it live](http://ideone.com/czYtqy)

Comment: what is your problem ?

Comment: std::copy gave me errors, it's considered unsafe.

Comment: BTW, you don't respect the [rule of three (five)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming)), `const` are missing, you may use `bool`, and `pop()` wrongly returns `char`.

Comment: Thank you, i changed pop() method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `memcpy`, the size of the memory you are copying must be given in bytes.

So, you have to multiply `sizeof(int)` with your `n`.